# Adding datalabels to Bar Chart in MS Access with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been trying to add data labels to my pivot charts programmatically through VBA, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've looked everywhere online, but nothing seems to work for my particular case.

```
Dim myForm As Form
Set myForm = Forms("My Form")
```

This may be fairly simple, but how do I access the 'HasDataLabels' property from there? I need to add it to two series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethen,

Here is a little VBA that can be used to add data labels to a form being viewed as a pie chart pivot chart. Please note, this code may cause errors if the form is not viewed as a pivot chart, because ChartSpace may not be available.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim FormChartSpace As owc10.ChartSpace

  Set FormChartSpace = Me.Form.ChartSpace
  FormChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).DataLabelsCollection.Add
  FormChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).DataLabelsCollection(0).HasValue = True
  Set FormChartSpace = Nothing
End Sub
```

You might find this link helpful as well: [Programming PivotTable Reports in Microsoft Access 2002](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139960%28v=office.10%29.aspx#odc_acprogpvt_filters)

There are many ways to format charts in Access VBA. It has turned out to be more robust for my users when I create the entire chart programmatically, this avoids problems with users accidentally "corrupting" the charts by unknowingly dragging controls, because the chart is recreated from scratch each time the form is loaded.

---

Using the code above requires a reference to OWC10 (Microsoft Office XP Web Components)

1. On the Tools menu, click References.
2. Click the Browse button.
3. Browse to the file C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OFFOWC.DLL. (The location can change based on the version of office you have)
4. Click the file, and then click Open. This adds a reference to the Microsoft Office XP Web Components library.
5. Click OK to close the References dialog box.